# Given that $U_{n+1} = U_n - U_n^2$ and $0 < U_0 < 1$ show that $0 < U_n < 1/4$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Given that $U_{n+1} = U_n-U_n^2$ and $0 < U_0 < 1$, show that $0 < U_n \leq 1/4$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$.

Given that $S_n$ is the sum of $\frac{1}{1-U_k}$ from k=0 to n

Calculate $S_n$ in function of n

I see that $\frac{1}{1-U_{n}}=\frac{1}{U_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{U_n}$

How can I calculate the sum ?

Comment: As in you don't know how to use induction, or you're not allowed to?

Comment: @πr8 yes I know how to use it ! But its confusing in this example i can't make $n=0$ and if $U_0<1$ this not mean that $U_0<1/4$

Comment: @user233658 I would assume that $\mathbb{N}^*$ denote the natural numbers $\geq 1$. So $U_n < 1/4$ does not have to hold for the special case of $n = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Show that $0<U_{n+1}<U_n$ for all $n$
2. Show that $U_1<1/4$ for any choice of $0<U_0<1$

Comment: Showing that $U_{n+1}<U_n$ comes after this question , we can defuce that $(U_n)$ is decreasing

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\frac{1}{4}-U_{n+1}=(U_n-\frac{1}{2})^2>0$. The inequality is strict because by the induction hypothesis $U_n\in(0,\frac{1}{4}]$ and so $U_n\neq\frac{1}{2}$. Similarly, $U_{n+1}=U_n(1-U_n)>0$ also because $U_n\in(0,\frac{1}{4}]$.

The base case is identical:
$$
\frac{1}{4}-U_1=(U_0-\frac{1}{2})^2\geq 0,\quad U_1=U_0(1-U_0)>0.
$$
For $U_n>U_{n+1}$ observe that $U_{n}-U_{n+1}=U_n^2>0$, for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @user233658 Because $\frac{1}{4}-U_1\geq 0$.